# Blender behaviour when minimizing / background mode

Tags: python, rendering

this is more of a general than a specific question, I hope that is alright.
I am trying to render multiple similar images iterativly with a python script. When running in background mode, it does not start rendering properly (due to me using a frame change handler, *I think*). When I run the script in normal GUI-mode, everything works fine. But when minimizing the Blender-window, I get the following error:

```
old_type =  bpy.context.area.ui_type
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui_type'
```

My question is now this: Were are the differences in GUI- and background-mode and what happens internally if I minimize Blender? I know that some *contexts* are different, but I do not know what that exactly entails.
If someone could explen/point me to an precise explanation the concepts of areas, viewports, windows and screens, that would be helpful too, because these terms always come up when I try to understand Blender, but I can't find a good explanation. The docs are not really helpful in understanding the concepts imo.

Comment: As I see it what is at play here is background or headless mode has no UI. Operators that rely on the UI will not work.  An example is posted in question where `context.area is None` since it is part of the UI and the UI is not available in headless mode.  It is very often the case that operators can be replaced by lower level API calls.

Comment: Was not aware of the issue when minimized, makes sense since `context.area` is defined by having the mouse over that area of the context screen in the context window..  Suggest a simple print of UI elements or a "context dump" `print(context.copy())`  If any are `None` eg `context.foo` then trying to use `context.foo.bar` will result in the error message above.